# Imported model has odd wireframe color

Tags: modeling

I have a model whose file type is 3D Object that i imported into blender as an OBJ. In object mode it looks fine but in edit mode the wireframe has an odd blue and black checker pattern. Can i make it look like the default black?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Edit Mode**, **Select all** - <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Clear Sharp**.

They are **Marked Sharp** and this is why it looks like this. It happens sometimes when importing .OBJ files or other formats.

[image: steps]

You can also check **Data tab** > **Geometry Data** for **Custom Normals**, they can cause troubles but they can also be good. So if want to get rid of them choose **Clear Custom Split Normals Data**.

[image: normals]

Comment: @evanf if my answer helped you consider accepting it and upvoting.